# How to convert Normal Android App to Android Auto App?

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

Hello Android Developers

I already have a Navigation Application that is almost completely developed.
now, I'd like to make this app work on Android Auto.
Of course, for distribution, I will have to do additional work to Google Auto App Guide Line.

However, above all, I can't even see the Icon of my app in Android Auto environment.
So, I would like to ask two questions.

first, We know that Android Auto has two methods: Media App or Message App.
Should I convert my car navigation app to one of the two?

second, Can I convert my Normal App to Auto App? If so, how is that? Do official documents exist?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to get the app apk format for Auto in Github, then try to get the proper bundle format for Auto. Or try to choose the Android Auto SDK in Android Studio.